No Sound - ALSA cannot find the correct Soundcard
I am trying to convert an Evolve III Maestro laptop into a Linux machine on the Xubuntu distribution; however, I am running into an issue where my machine isn't able to output audio to the speakers or headphones (though it is able to output to Bluetooth).
I believe that downloading and installing Realtek HD Audio Drivers will help, but Realtek appears to have overhauled their website and has removed their downloads for Audio Drivers.
My suspicion is that this is a driver issue - though I am not able to find a place to download those drivers. How should I go about getting my audio to work on this computer?
pacmd list-cards returns 0 cards.
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio returns an Audio device for Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster [8086:5a98] (rev 0b).
aplay -l returns 3 Playback Hardware devices: all listed as sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], then as device 1, 2, or 3 for HDMI1, HDMI2, or HDMI3. There are no other audio device listed here other than those three.
find /lib/modules/'uname -r' | grep pci-intel returns 5 results, all within lib/modules/5.15.0-105-generic/kernel/sound/soc/sof/intel and starting with snd-sof-pci-intel- followed by either cnl.ko, apl.ko, tng.ko, tgl.ko, or icl.ko.
PulseAudio Volume Controller shows no output devices aside from Dummy Output. I have reinstalled alsa and PulseAudio a number of times to no avail.
I have also gone into the BIOS and disabled and re-enabled HD Audio.

You'll probably missing the right driver. Over at the Mint community are some threads about your device or this thread

It seems part of the problem was solved by following these instructions:
https://github.com/gnickm/sof-essx8336-debian-fix
Basically, installing the fix there for debian and installing the new kernel. While this ended up making the soundcard available in pulseaudio, it still wasn't outputting audio here.
pacmd list-cards is still failing to return any cards. I suspect that that is now the issue.
